# Is there any way to induce a custom functionality in measure annotation tool bar in HighStocks? Not the styles and CSS but the functionality

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a requirement where I have to customize the measure annotation toolBar. I have to include a span or button inside it and on click of which I want to go to the bottom of my screen. I know the styles of the toolbar can be overwritten, but what about adding a new span. I am giving below the screen shots of what highstocks provide and how I want it. Thanks in advance.

How Highstocks provide:

[image]

How I need it:

[image]

Comment: In the case of just styling changes, the best option is doing it via CSS. If you want to overwrite the current logic you will need to wrap the `showPopup` feature in the core. https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Comment: Hello, Yes this is something which I am already aware of. Basically we can write a new pop-up in the showPopup and hide the existing one using CSS. But this is something which I want to avoid and rather edit the existing toolbar just like we can edit the stock tool bar as to which button I want and which I dont.(eg.  buttons:['measure','zoomChange']). Is it Possible?

Comment: I am afraid that rewriting the `showPopup` feature is only one possible solution. API doesn't offer any options for this case.